# How were the software such as Ubuntu software center created?

Tags: application-development

What programming languages were used to create software like Ubuntu Software Center or System Monitor?  How was the GUI created?
The reason I am interested is that I need to create a desktop application on Ubuntu.

Comment: Note that there are many ways to create Linux desktop apps beyond Python and GTK. Do some research and find out what best suits your project / needs before getting started.

Comment: @JonasCz can you share what are the other ways?  I will also search.

Comment: Examples of programming languages with GUI support on Linux include Java, [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) (Great if you like working with web technologies), C# via [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/), QT, which has bindings for many languages, including C, C++, and more. There's many others though, look for something like "[your preferred language]" Linux GUI". If you need your app to be cross-platform, make sure that whatever you use works on all the platforms you need (Windows, Mac..). Most of the apps that come with Ubuntu use GTK, and are written in either C, C++, or Python.